# What glyphs should I use as a solo top?

Tags: league-of-legends

For example, I pick Gangplank to run as a solo top for my team and build tanky. I've considered running MR glyphs, but does this give full potential? I feel it doesn't simply because you face mainly AD bruisers or AD tanks.

What glyphs should I run and why?

Comment: I love game jargon, I have no idea what any of this means.

Comment: He asked whether he should boost his magic resistance against other players who beat the crap out his ass (without magic) or not? The question doesn't make much sense to me either.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to pick your rune page based on the enemy champion. So, have a page of flat MR runes if they try to run Ryze or Kennen top, have a page with mana regeneration if you need to harass a champion out of lane, etc.

Having a page with flat MR and flat armor should cover most situations.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 3 pages you should make a mixed page with armor yellows and mr blues for your bruisers. Many ad champs like Shyvanna do a good amount of magic damage anyways and if you play against an ap champ it's nice to have armor for their jungler. I personally always run armor and mr for my toplaners.

Answer (score 0):

With the removal of crit chance from masteries, I find using some runes for crit chance for some champs like gangplank and tryndamere to be worthwhile if you like solo top.  Of course, it depends on what lane you are facing, however the simple benefit of being able to land a few lucky crits will instantly give yourself a huge advantage in early game trades is worth it in my opinion.

That said, I tend to use mr/level glyphs as I find magic resist to be the most efficient use of glyphs when you are short of IP to buy any rune you want.  If you are on the tournament realm, this of course would not mean anything and you have the freedom to spec like you might see in competitive play where they will run runepages that give 30+ armor or 30+ magic resist so they can handle trading a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

Glyphs (or Blues as some people call them) Are NORMALLY Flat MRs / MR/lvl across the board. But really, it is all up to summoner preference. I would suggest reading guides on top lane champs over on http://www.solomid.net/ and decide from there.

But for the most part, MR / MR/lvl  are my picks (especially since Blues/ Glyphs have stonger magic-based runeset than anything else); unless I need some Mana regen as well as armor, in which case I would take the armor Yellows/Seals and the Mana Regen Blues/Glyphs)

Answer (score 0):

MR/lvl are the best. Usually, you should take 3 flat runes and 6 scaling, that way you have enough MR on lvl 1 to counter their Mpen (if against an AP champ top) adn you have scaling MR runes.